# What is the path of file for export csv of products

Tags: magento, csv, path

I wanna just know the path of the file where i can customize the code for export csv of products as per my need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create export.csv on root ..write a code to export csv the new thing is that you have to hardcode base url in the path of the product..

for example ..existing path category/product/

base url/category/product/

But remember to keep the code correct..